# ActiveAdmin Alternatives

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, admin, administrator, activeadmin

I have been using the pretty looking [active admin](http://activeadmin.info/) recently and ran in to some issues happening across my application with a performance issue and other things including the taking over of the clean and nice "search" keyword used by the Sunspot gem (like Model.search) which is replaced by the meta_search.

So I am now unhappy with ActiveAdmin and would like to see if there are some nice alternatives out there that can give a good administration framework as well as give the ability to browse data, since I will be deploying on heroku and browsing the database directly there without something like active_admin is not that simple.

Any suggestions or pointers to admin frameworks will be much appreciated

Comment: That is a shame, I like the flexibility of ActiveAdmin because RailsAdmin doesn't support custom actions.

Comment: please checkout activeadmin cool things here - http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/activeadmin-cool-tweaks/

Comment: I built an alternative myself (Forest Admin) that is specific in the way that it provides you with a remote UI as a service. 

https://medium.com/forest-admin/forest-admin-vs-active-admin-the-complete-comparison-4cfcfbfee74c

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I can think of:

- [RailsAdmin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin): supported by rails-core
- [Typus](https://github.com/fesplugas/typus): seems very powerful

I also found an (older) [article](http://www.viget.com/extend/rails-admin-interface-generators/) doing a comparison of the three.

[EDIT: update March 2018]

The above seem still relevant, but there are new some new kids on the block:

- [trestle](https://trestle.io/) seems very promising imho: clean, responsive, modern (my current fav!)
- [administrate](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate) built by thoughtbot, and aims to improve upon rails-admin and active-admin by simplifying it actually (e.g. no DSL's). Interesting approach

To my surprise I noticed that the first gem I used for this purpose is still actively being developed: [activescaffold](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold)

Also for future reference check [the ruby-toolbox's relevant category](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_admin_interfaces) .

Answer (score 17):

Have a look at [RailsAdmin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin). Here's a quick comparison of the two - RailsAdmin and ActiveAdmin serve different purposes - RailsAdmin is intended to provide an admin UI that usable out-of-the-box with little or no manual tweaking, whereas ActiveAdmin is more or less a scaffold (or a framework) for building admin interfaces. Generally you can build more flexible UIs with ActiveAdmin, but this require more effort on your part. My suggestion to Rails devs is always the same - try out RailsAdmin first and if it's not good enough for you develop a custom UI with ActiveAdmin.

I've written a [fairly extensive article on the subject](http://batsov.com/articles/2011/11/20/admin-interfaces-for-rails-apps-railsadmin-vs-activeadmin/). You might want to check it out. The comments of the article mention some other nice options you can consider.

Answer (score 6):

There is another alternative dashboard - [administrate](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate) by [thoughtbot](https://github.com/thoughtbot).

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing similar issues with Active Admin and I couldn’t find any better alternatives.

So I decided to build [Forest Admin](https://www.forestadmin.com).

I wrote an article to understand how Forest Admin differs from ActiveAdmin and what issues we focussed on solving:
[Forest Admin vs Active Admin](https://medium.com/forest-admin/forest-admin-vs-active-admin-the-complete-comparison-4cfcfbfee74c)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at new gem [Upmin Admin Ruby](https://github.com/upmin/upmin-admin-ruby). Looks very promising.